# КМП алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм

Привет.

Это снова я, и я до сих пор не понял, как именно работает алгоритм Кнута-Морриса-Пратта. Ну никак.
Что я понял: что такое префикс-функция, а также то, что КМП использует префикс-функцию, выполненную для образца, чтобы ускорить поиск.
Что не понял: как выполненная префикс-функция для образца помогает увеличить скорость поиска. Например, строка и образец:

```
text = "aaaaazaaabcbaaaab"
pattern = "aaab"

prefix_function(pattern) = 0120
```

Теперь кто-нибудь сможет, *не привязываясь к коду и к индексации (i, j)*, объяснить, как же КМП алгоритм использует "0120" для ускорения поиска.

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/prefix_function  
здесь все популярно объяснено в разделе Применения.

Comment: Там (Поиск подстроки в строке. Алгоритм Кнута-Морриса-Пратта ), кстати, совсем не КМП. Там тупо используется префикс-функция. А КМП же использует префикс функцию для рациональных сдвигов по образцу при осуществлении поиска.

Comment: @thejadefalcon вообще-то там как раз таки и показывают, как, используя "префикс(pattern) + разделитель + текст", применить префикс-функцию для поиска. А в первом параграфе показано, как именно формируются значения результирующего массива префикс функции и что они обозначают. Вам уже давали эту ссылку, но вы упорно продолжаете не понимать.

Comment: @smackmychi Я Вам говорю, как человек, пересмотревший кучу источников - это не то применение, о котором я указал в вопросе.
Смотрите. Если применить п-ф для pattern#text, мы можем посмотреть в результате, где элемент равен длине образца, и тогда мы можем найти легко точку вхождения образца в текст, но если все так легко, смотрите тогда:
https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/kmp_matcher - зачем тут дополнительная сложная kmpMatcher функция, которая применяет префикс-функцию для образца? Если Вы читали мой другой вопрос, Вы должны были увидеть, что писал @avp насчет экономии памяти.

Comment: @thejadefalcon она не сложная. Просто так туго записана. Это задача олимпиадная. Если так трудно понять, что происходит - возьмите направление решения олимпиадных задач и смотрите, почему не находится префикс-функция от текста, а только от образца и на чем это допущение основано. В итоге получается, что, не вычисляя префикс-функцию для текста, мы экономим и время, и память. А используем префикс-функцию для образца, чтобы уменьшить количество сравнений (можете на листочке посмотреть, как будет меняться K с каждой итерацией, но текст берите короткий).

Comment: Ну, Вы можете на словах объяснить, потому что я уже неделю не могу понять этот чертов алгоритм.

Comment: @thejadefalcon я же говорю - возьмите этот алгоритм (я так понимаю, именно то решение, где префикс-функция вычисляется только для образца) и тупо каждую итерацию разберите на конкретном примере - берете и на листочке записываете те данные, которые есть, после чего сами выполняете с ними определенные действия (можно и какой-нибудь отладчик использовать, если совсем лень и смотреть по шагам). Может быть, здесь вы увидите, в чем суть, просто на Java очень коряво записано: http://chasolimp.ucoz.com/publ/5-1-0-8  
Может, вам стоит и отложить эту задачу на время. Скорее всего самое верное решение.